# Not able to get data from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, handler

I've seen many old posts on this issue and I've followed them with no success.

I created a jetty server with multiple handlers following this: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyConnectors.java. I have one handler for http and another for https. The handlers extend the AbstractHandler and only have the handle() method implemented.

I'm able to reach both handlers (I can see that via logging) using Postman to send requests and data but I have 2 problems.

1. Whether I use POST, PUT or GET, the HttpServletRequest.getMethod() always returns "GET".
2. I can't figure out how to get the data send via POST. Even though HttpServletRequest.getReader() is not null, I'm just not getting any data.
   I added a bunch of logging in here to see what's going on. Hope that helps because it hasn't helped me.

```
 public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    
    private static Logger logger = new L4Logger(MyHandler.class);

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("MyHandler", "handle request " + request.getMethod() + " for path " + request.getContextPath());
        
        logger.info("MyHandler", "content length " + request.getContentLength());
        
        Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames();
        Collections.list(e).forEach(s -> {logger.info("MyHandler", "handle e " + s);});
        
        Enumeration<String> a = request.getAttributeNames();
        Collections.list(a).forEach(s -> {logger.info("MyHandler", "handle a " + s);});
        
        if (request.getReader() == null) {
            logger.info("MyHandler", "handle request request.getReader() == null");
        } else {
            logger.info("MyHandler", "handle request request.getReader() != null");
        }
        
        if (request.getContextPath().equalsIgnoreCase("/run")) {
            logger.info("MyHandler", "handle request run");
            String cmdString = getBody(request);
            logger.info("MyHandler", "handle run data " + cmdString);
        }
        
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
    
    private String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

POSTing my server with some json data, the log output looks like this:

```
[handle request GET for path /run]
 [content length -1]
 [handle a javax.servlet.request.key_size]
 [handle a org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session]
 [handle a javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate]
 [handle a javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite]
 [handle a javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id]
 [handle request request.getReader() != null]
 [handle request run]
 [handle run data ]
```

And lastly, here's the cURL command exported from Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:7777/run' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Cookie: ssoLang=en' --data-raw '[{"cmd":"ls","args":"/proc"}]'
```

Comment: Add verbose output to the curl line `curl -vvvv ...`, run it again, and then edit your question with the output it produced.  it could reveal something useful. (like it not following redirects correctly with POST requests).

Comment: After much trial and error and frustration, I abandoned this approach and went with using the RESTful solution described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206312/how-to-make-jersey-servlet-to-load-more-than-one-service-or-class-in-java-rest-a . This solution is sufficient for what I need and I got it working in a couple of hours so I abandoned my initial approach.

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Length` of -1 is a potential sign on what's going on.

The `Content-Type` header also controls behavior here a great deal.

Dump/Log all of the Request Headers, look for `Content-Length`, `Transfer-Encoding`, `Content-Encoding`, etc...  pretty much all of the relevant ones that control the request body content disposition.

Example: Verify that your request header is actually `Content-Type: application/json`.

You can do this with `curl -vvvv` to dump the request/response headers on the command line.

And you can do this on the server side with ...

```java
logger.info("MyHandler", "request content-type: " + request.getHeader("Content-Type"));
```

If it's not what you expect, then it's likely the Standard Servlet behavior.

When you use any of the following methods ...

- [HttpServletRequest.getParameter(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-)
- [HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap--)
- [HttpServletRequest.getParameterNames()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames--)
- [HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-)
- [HttpServletRequest.getParts()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts--)
- [HttpServletRequest.getPart(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart-java.lang.String-)

And the the request is using `POST` method and with the special `Content-Type` values ...

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- `multipart/form-data` (and your endpoint that has a `javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement` defined).

then you are ALSO reading the body content.

There's no data left to read on the request after those method calls.

Comment: This is driving me crazy. I ran the curl from cygwin with the debugging you suggested and now I see:
~~~
[Content-Type, application/json]
[request content-type: application/json length -1]
[method POST]
[handle run data ]
~~~
Though I'm not getting data, the method is POST and the content is JSON. I reran the same thing from postman and it's back to GET and the content-type is null.
~~~
[request content-type: null length -1]
[method GET]
[handle run data ]
~~~